# iOS App says "No longer Available" after my license had been expired?

Tags: ios, licensing

I have developed an application for a customer and gave it to him.
He had just installed it and was using it...

Now my license had been expired, and now all of a sudden he says that his app says:
`{my_app} "No longer Available"`
[ **Note**: He didn't reinstall the application so far].

Can anyone help me with this weird behavior...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will no longer appear on the app store if you don't have an active developer license.

If you didn't put it on the app store and just **gave it to them via ad hoc** or something, the provisioning profile *has probably expired* so you would need to renew that, which would need an active developer licence as well.

Comment: So what will be the life time of the provisional profile ??

Comment: they are only valid for a year i think

Comment: Thanks for your answer......But consider like this - I have an app in app store and a some ppl downloaded it,and now if my license expired...Even they cant use the app??

Comment: no i think if your app is in the app store and your licence expires, it just wont be available for download anymore, users that have the app already  will still keep theirs though. if current user has the app and deletes it and tries to reinstall though im not sure if they can or not

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @Fonix answer.

If you didn't have a paid apple account membership (~ 99 $) and used the `free provisioning` by using XCode deploy directly into your client device, then:
The `free provisioning` profiles are **only valid for one week**.

Comment: I was searching everywhere for this specific answer (how long does free provisioning cert last / anyway to change it to last longer).  I posted a question about it here at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014121/how-do-i-extend-the-amount-of-time-my-provisioning-certificate-is-valid-for-my-i
Would you happen to have the source of your information -- like apple dev site?
Also, it seems that if I get an official Dev account then provisioning will be for up to 1 year, right?