# How do I extend the amount of time my provisioning certificate is valid for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate, ios-provisioning

**Background**

I've written an iOS app which is for "Home Use" at this time.
I have a locally provisioned certificate in XCode for my app so I can install it on my devices.
I've been running the app for 6 or 7 days on my local iPhone.

**App No Longer Available**

Today I got the error "App No Longer Available" when I try to run it.
I found the [SO Entry that lists reason why this might be happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896128/app-is-no-longer-available), but I know why.
I checked XCode and discovered that the provisioning cert only lasts 6 days.
So annoying!!

**Provision App For Longer?**

However, I don't know how to provision the app for longer?

How do I set up the cert to last longer?

Can this only be done by having a full apple dev account?
Really hope not.

[image: xcode provisioning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the definitive answer at: [iOS App says "No longer Available" after my license had been expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646382/ios-app-says-no-longer-available-after-my-license-had-been-expired?noredirect=1&lq=1)  (Though it is not the answer to the other question there.)

### Definitive Answer

#### Without Official Apple Dev Account

If you don't have an official Apple Dev Account provisioning will only last for 1 week.  The app will expire every 7 days (or less in some cases -- depending upon the day the initial certificate was created).

#### With Official Apple Dev Account

You will be able to provision your app for up to 1 year.

This is gleaned from other comments on the linked answer.
It may not be true any more.

###############################

Here's a partial answer that I got to through a lot of searching.

I found out that in XCode, you can go to :

XCode => Preferences...

[image: xcode preferences]

A dialog will appear and then you should choose the `Accounts` tab

[image: account info]

There is a manage certificates button here.  click it.

[image: certificate info]

You can click the small [+] button on the lower left but it is really unhelpful.

This adds a certificate, but notice that you cannot tell when the expiration date is and the `Status` column shows no information at all.

There is no way to select or edit any of the certs here.

This is ridiculously complicated.  I'm sure it is just to push devs to create an official apple account & pay the fee.

Comment: As you have discovered, you need a paid account. With a paid account your provisioning profiles will expire on the date that your yearly membership ends